# Many-to-Many query without duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables and a ration table in between.

```
Brands
------
id, name, img

Country
-------
id, name
```

Each country can have different brands. Likewise, a brand can be in different countries. A many-to-many relationship. That is why I have added a pivot table.

```
country_brands
--------------
country_id, brand_id
```

**My goal:** A SQL select that gives me all brands from country 1!

**What I have already done:**
I use this query: `SELECT b.id, b.name FROM brands b inner JOIN country_brands cb ON cb.country_id = 1;`

**Problem:** I get all the brands for country 1 but I have a lot of duplicates.

**Question:** What do I have to change to get only one brand.id per country instead of all links?

#### UPDATE

One Solition from @Jens would to JOIN both tables (brands and countries).
And I wonder if you can't just do a Group By. I can't judge now which variant is more perfomant. Like that:
`SELECT b.id, b.name FROM brands b inner JOIN country_brands cb ON cb.country_id = 1 GROUP BY b.name;`

```
// I want / I expect
id, name
1 brand 1
2 brand 2
4 brand 4

// but I get:

1 brand 1
1 brand 1
1 brand 1
1 brand 1
...
2. brand 2
2 brand 2
..
4. brand 4
...
```

Thanks! Max

Answer (score 1):

You have to join both tables:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name FROM brands b inner JOIN country_brands cb ON cb.brand_id = brands.id 
JOIN Country c ON cb.country_id = c.id 
where c.id=1;
```